# How to generate SNMP events in .Net 2.0

Tags: wmi, snmp

Can anyone advise me how through an example, or whether it is possible to  generate SNMP events in .Net using Framework 2.0 and for those events to be monitored using windows tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SNMP protocol does not define anything called events. Do you mean by notifications? An SNMP engine/agent can raise notificates (TRAP or INFORM messages) over UDP to its dedicated SNMP managers, so that the managers know something happens.

If that's what you mean, you may use any SNMP library that supports .NET 2.

http://www.lextm.com/2007/12/product-review-snmp-libraries-for-net.html

But .NET 2 is too old, and even Microsoft no longer supports .NET 2 unless you are also installing .NET 3.5 SP1 on the same machine. Therefore, you may consider targeting .NET 3.5 directly instead of 2.0.

Comment: Basically, what I am trying to achieve is to use WMI with custom SNMP traps on an application - is this possible?

Comment: WMI+SNMP is something Microsoft/Windows only (not even .NET specific), so you should not only use 'snmp' tag. Besides, your question description is ambiguous. Therefore, try to modify it.